# Find function f(x)

Tags: functions, derivatives

Find function f(x), where:
$$f(3)=3$$
$$f'(3)=3$$
$$f'(4)=4$$
$$f''(3) = \nexists$$

How to find function like this in **general?** What steps should I do?

Comment: What is the meaning of the last line ? f''(3) = ?

Comment: second derivative does not exist at 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a family of functions with some free parameters (in this case, you have three equations, so you should be going for three parametrs) and then slowly adjust the parameters.

1. Start with $A|x-3|+B$, which is a function that does not have a derivative at $3$.
2. This means that $\int A|x-3|+Bdx$ (which has derivatives everywhere) has no second derivative at $3$
3. Calculating the integral gives $$f_{A,B,C} = \begin{cases}-A(\frac{x^2}{2}+3x )+Bx +C& x\leq 3\\A(\frac{x^2}2 - 3x)+Bx + C & x\geq 3\end{cases}$$ which is a function that has no second derivative at $3$.
4. Now you simply calculate $f_{A,B,C}(3)$, $f'_{A,B,C}(3)$ and $f'_{A,B,C}(4)$ to determine what the values of $A,B,C$ should be.

The values you get should be $$3=f_{A,B,C}(3) = -\frac{27}{2}A + 3B + C\\ 3=f'_{A,B,C}(3) = B\\
4=f'_{A,B,C}(4) = A+B$$
Which is easy to solve if you do it in the right order (first solve for $B$, then $A$, then $C$)

Comment: Thanks a lot! $A|x-3|+B$ is f'(x) Am I true? When function does not have derivative in some point it means that it is not possible plug in number into function, because there is no variable (x) ?

Comment: @DavidM Yes, the derivative is $A|x-3|+B$, but what do you mean by "there is no variable (x)"?!

Comment: $A|x-3|+B$ is f'(x), and f''(x) = 1, it means that f''(3) = does not exist, because i cant plug in 3 into f''(x)??

Comment: @DavidM $f''(x)$ is **most certainly not** equal to $1$. $|x|$ is the **absolute value**.

Answer (score 1):

Take a function $|x|$ which has no derivative at 0. Integrate it to get a function $x\cdot|x|$ (yes, $1\over2$ is missing, but who cares) which has no *second* derivative at 0. Shift it to get $(x-3)|x-3|$ which has no second derivative at 3. Add some $const\cdot x^2$ to get $f'(4)-f'(3)=1$. Then add some $const\cdot x$ to get whatever derivative you like at 3. Then add a constant to get the desired value at 3.